# How to Exit Programatically Created Browser in JScript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, jscript

I have the following `JScript` which opens Internet Explorer, navigates to the current users' Lync Response Group Settings page, and clicks on one of the checkboxes found there:

```
var ie = WSH.CreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
    url = "https://LyncServer.DOMAIN.co.uk/RgsClients/Tab.aspx",

ie.visible = true;
ie.Navigate(url);
while (ie.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(25);

ie.document.getElementById('ctl05_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl01').click();
```

Once this is done, I want the script to close the browser window.

I tried the following:

```
ie.exit()
ie.close()
ie.document.exit()
ie.document.close()
```

But got this error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: The first result when when [Googling "InternetExplorer.Application"](https://www.google.com/#q=InternetExplorer.Application) is the MSDN page [InternetExplorer object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx). The example at the bottom ends with `IE.Quit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Use `ie.Quit()`.

---

This has nothing to do with VBScript vs. JScript. What you call "the JavaScript close command" is the **DOM** (not JS) **method** (not "command") of the [**Window object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). Usually the DOM is the thing you manipulate with JS code that runs **inside** the browser as part of the HTML it's displaying.

This is unrelated to the `InternetExplorer` automation object. This method describes the Internet Explorer program, not the HTML page that is displayed in it right now. For example, it has a property that controls whether or not you're in "Offline browsing" mode. That's not part of the DOM.

This object has a bunch of other methods and properties which are mostly documented in the MSDN page I linked above - [`InternetExplorer` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx). Specifically, it implements the [`IWebBrowser2` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=vs.85).aspx) which means it implements the [`IWebBrowser2::Quit` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752140(v=vs.85).aspx).

Which is, obviously, unrelated to the WSH `WScript.Quit(errorCode)` method. Their signatures aren't even compatible. The WSH method returns an (optional) error code, the IE method doesn't.